# Socket IO date becomes string

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I try to emit a date from server to client although on client side the date becomes string and I have to always use `new Date()` on the string to convert it to date again.

Moreover, when I send an event through socket from client to server and then server returns date to client via callback it's also becomes a string.

And it works for both side, i.e. when I send date from client to server it also becomes string on server side.

**Is there a way to avoid converting and use it as a date right away?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. If you send data over the network, you'll have to serialize it. It is here automatically converted as a `string`, but nothing forbids you to transform it in whatever other format you'd like first, and do the opposite on the other end. Without too much hassle, you can pretty much send anything convertible into a JSON.

What happens is that for the transfer to happen, any data you want to send has to be [serialized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization). The method of choice for socket.io (and JS in general) is to use the JSON standard.

Anything you send will first be transformed into [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html), which can only store a very limited range of elements. Anything will be transformed in either a primitive type like `string` or `number`, or in the only two non-primitive types that JSON supports, which are `object`s and `array`s.

So pretty much anything that's not primitive and not an array will be converted into an object, only keeping serializable properties. That's done by calling the `toJSON` property of the data you want to send. In your case, the `toJSON` method of a `Date` returns his string representation, and that's what gets sent in the end.

```js
const date = new Date();    // Your date
console.log(date.toJSON()); // What will be sent
```

Comment: I don't think this answers the question, because things like numbers and objects come out of Socket.IO as numbers and objects, not strings. Can you edit your answer to explain how Dates are different?

Comment: The question - before it got edited - contained many more tags than now, making it look broader than it looks now. Moreover, you edited the tags out after the answer got accepted, making it look too broad indeed. I'll still add an explanation.